# Firebase authentication with onCompleteListener not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, listener

I am trying to implement a basic android authentication system with Firebase. The following is my code:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BEFORE ON-COMPLETE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //this shows up
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailInputted, passInputted).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "in OnComplete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this does not show up
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
                i.putExtra("EMAIL", emailInputted);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please check email/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "after OnComplete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this shows up
```

I took this code from the official [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth), but for some reason it is not working. The `onComplete` method is not being called for some reason. I can see the "before on-Complete" and "after on-complete" toasts, but not the "in OnComplete" one. I have added the users in my authentication table in the firebase console, and I am positive that I am entering the correct password.

After using the debugger, I saw that my code just skips over the `onComplete()` method, and does not even get to the `isSuccessful()` method. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, did you try adding `addOnCanceledListener` and putting a log or breakpoint to see if something is going wrong ? Like empty pass or email for example

Comment: @tperraut Just did, `onCanceledListner` does not get called. I checked Firebase status on https://status.firebase.google.com/, but there seem to be no known issues at the time? Also, I am checking for empty passwords/emails beforehand. I don't think that's the issue

Comment: What happens if you use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` instead ?

Comment: @tperraut Just tried that with a similar code. `Before onComplete` and `After onComplete` toasts get called, but not the `in onComplete` one. Also, no user has been created in my authentication table.

Comment: Did you activate the email authentication on firebase ? https://ibb.co/hVptM2S

Comment: Yep! I am positive that email authentication is turned on, and I am entering the correct details

Comment: And if you try other functions on FirebaseAuth lib like `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` it works ? You get null as expected ?

Comment: Yep. I am getting Null for `mAuth.getCurrentUser()`

Comment: Just to make sure that you have **already added** [android.permission.INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Lol. It sounds bizarre for me to point out but many a times we forget to add this permission and countless hours of debugging is fruitless for such a trivial mistake.

Comment: Yep lol. It is there. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this, I hop you will get your answer.

```
lBut = findViewById(R.id.log_btn);
        lBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String a = usrn.getText().toString().trim();
                String b = pswd.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(a) && TextUtils.isEmpty(b)) {
                    usrn.setError("Empty Email !!");
                    pswd.setError("Empty Password !!");

                    lBut.setClickable(false);
                } else {
                    lBut.setClickable(true);
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(a, b).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Login!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeP.class);
                                ProgressBar prb = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                                prb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            } else
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Error And Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
```

This is the Event on the Login Button, you have more doubt then reply me.

Comment: Nope. This does not work :( onComplete isn't called at all

Comment: onComplete is called, see it clearly. and in onComplete Functions I have featured login Message

Comment: Now, I have to give you whole java file source code ??

Answer (score 0):

So it fixed itself after I restarted my computer. No code changes. Maybe Android Studio was being wacky.